# ImportError: cannot import name when running pytest

Tags: python, python-import, pytest

My directory structure is like so:

```
├── person
     └── __init__.py
     └── person.py
└── tests
     └── test_person.py
├── setup.py
```

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="person", packages=find_packages())
```

**person.py:**

```
import team


class Person:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname


print("hello")
```

**test_person.py:**

```
from person import Person


def test_person():
    p = Person("john", "smith")
    assert p.fname == "john"
```

After installing my package:

```
$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///Users/raphattack/PyCharm/person
Installing collected packages: person
  Running setup.py develop for person
Successfully installed person
```

I am hitting this error:

```
$ pytest
======================================================================= test session starts ========================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.8.1, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: /Users/raphattack/PyCharm/person, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

============================================================================== ERRORS ==============================================================================
______________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_person.py _______________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/raphattack/PyCharm/person/tests/test_person.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_person.py:1: in <module>
    from person import Person
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'Person'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
===================================================================== 1 error in 0.10 seconds ======================================================================
```

If I modify the import to `from person.person import Person` then it runs. How can I make it so that I only need `from person import Person`?

**Edit:** [@hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling)'s suggestion works well, but I am hitting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'team'` error if my `person.py` imports `team`. how can I modify `__init__.py` so that pytest will pick up the other module?

**team.py**

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

This works:

```
$ python3 person/person.py
hello
```

This doesn't:

```
$ pytest
======================================================================= test session starts =======================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.8.1, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: /Users/raphattack/PyCharm/person, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

============================================================================= ERRORS ==============================================================================
______________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_person.py ______________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/raphattack/PyCharm/person/tests/test_person.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_person.py:1: in <module>
    from person import Person
person/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .person import Person
person/person.py:1: in <module>
    import team
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'team'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
===================================================================== 1 error in 0.11 seconds =====================================================================
```

Comment: Add  `from .person import Person` to `person/__init__.py` file.

Comment: Thanks! Is this the recommended directory structure and import convention or would you modify anything?

Comment: It's a common one and there's nothing wrong with it. Still, you may be interested in reading [Good Integration Practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) for examples of another layouts that may or may not suit you better.

Comment: Thanks! This is working well for `person.py`, but when I extend the above to `import team`, it is not picking up the module. Can you give an example of how I might do this?